# Fastest hashing method under OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, hashsum

I frequently verify the file integrity on my OpenWrt router by hashing the files. I didn't want to use `sha256sum`, so I decided to use the faster `md5sum`. Is there anything even faster available?

Comment: Quick question - why do you need to regularly check file integrity? It sounds like there may be a wider issue that is worth solving?

Comment: Are you concerned with accidental damage, truncated files, or potentially malicious attackers? If the latter, you're not going to do much better at this level, but there's quite probably a better way of achieving your overall security goal. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: the problem is: "sometimes ex.: pictures get corrupted [but this is rarely] so that I want to detect the problem before the users see that xy picture file on the router cannot be accessed anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to guard against malicious damage, then MD5 is the fastest hash which is secure enough (although it does have known weaknesses and so SHA2 is strongly preferred). If you just want to guard against accidental damage, then a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) checksum will be faster and good enough. The standard [`cksum`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cksum.1.html) utility can be used to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

I compared Gnu/Linux checksum programs (not including CRC) just a couple months ago and found md5sum to be the fastest. I wouldn't think any of its vulnerabilities would apply in the case you describe.